# HIghCharts. DataLables not show. IE8

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highcharts gauges. Work perfectly in Chrome.

however the gauge datalable does not appear in IE8.

how to display solidgauge's datalabels of highcharts in IE8?

in chrome, datalabels display OK.

thanks in advance..

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {



    /**
     * Dark theme for Highcharts JS
     * @author Torstein Honsi
     */

    // Load the fonts
    Highcharts.createElement('link', {
       href: 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Unica+One',
       rel: 'stylesheet',
       type: 'text/css'
    }, null, document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]);

    Highcharts.theme = {
       colors: ["#2b908f", "#90ee7e", "#f45b5b", "#7798BF", "#aaeeee", "#ff0066", "#eeaaee",
          "#55BF3B", "#DF5353", "#7798BF", "#aaeeee"],
       chart: {
          backgroundColor: {
             linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 1, y2: 1 },
             stops: [
                [0, '#2a2a2b'],
                [1, '#3e3e40']
             ]
          },
          style: {
             fontFamily: "'Unica One', sans-serif"
          },
          plotBorderColor: '#606063'
       },
       title: {
          style: {
             color: '#E0E0E3',
             textTransform: 'uppercase',
             fontSize: '20px'
          }
       },
       subtitle: {
          style: {
             color: '#E0E0E3',
             textTransform: 'uppercase'
          }
       },
       xAxis: {
          gridLineColor: '#707073',
          labels: {
             style: {
                color: '#E0E0E3'
             }
          },
          lineColor: '#707073',
          minorGridLineColor: '#505053',
          tickColor: '#707073',
          title: {
             style: {
                color: '#A0A0A3'

             }
          }
       },
       yAxis: {
          gridLineColor: '#707073',
          labels: {
             style: {
                color: '#E0E0E3'
             }
          },
          lineColor: '#707073',
          minorGridLineColor: '#505053',
          tickColor: '#707073',
          tickWidth: 1,
          title: {
             style: {
                color: '#A0A0A3'
             }
          }
       },
       tooltip: {
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85)',
          style: {
             color: '#F0F0F0'
          }
       },
       plotOptions: {
          series: {
             dataLabels: {
                color: '#B0B0B3'
             },
             marker: {
                lineColor: '#333'
             }
          },
          boxplot: {
             fillColor: '#505053'
          },
          candlestick: {
             lineColor: 'white'
          },
          errorbar: {
             color: 'white'
          }
       },
       legend: {
          itemStyle: {
             color: '#E0E0E3'
          },
          itemHoverStyle: {
             color: '#FFF'
          },
          itemHiddenStyle: {
             color: '#606063'
          }
       },
       credits: {
          style: {
             color: '#666'
          }
       },
       labels: {
          style: {
             color: '#707073'
          }
       },

       drilldown: {
          activeAxisLabelStyle: {
             color: '#F0F0F3'
          },
          activeDataLabelStyle: {
             color: '#F0F0F3'
          }
       },

       navigation: {
          buttonOptions: {
             symbolStroke: '#DDDDDD',
             theme: {
                fill: '#505053'
             }
          }
       },

       // scroll charts
       rangeSelector: {
          buttonTheme: {
             fill: '#505053',
             stroke: '#000000',
             style: {
                color: '#CCC'
             },
             states: {
                hover: {
                   fill: '#707073',
                   stroke: '#000000',
                   style: {
                      color: 'white'
                   }
                },
                select: {
                   fill: '#000003',
                   stroke: '#000000',
                   style: {
                      color: 'white'
                   }
                }
             }
          },
          inputBoxBorderColor: '#505053',
          inputStyle: {
             backgroundColor: '#333',
             color: 'silver'
          },
          labelStyle: {
             color: 'silver'
          }
       },

       navigator: {
          handles: {
             backgroundColor: '#666',
             borderColor: '#AAA'
          },
          outlineColor: '#CCC',
          maskFill: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.1)',
          series: {
             color: '#7798BF',
             lineColor: '#A6C7ED'
          },
          xAxis: {
             gridLineColor: '#505053'
          }
       },

       scrollbar: {
          barBackgroundColor: '#808083',
          barBorderColor: '#808083',
          buttonArrowColor: '#CCC',
          buttonBackgroundColor: '#606063',
          buttonBorderColor: '#606063',
          rifleColor: '#FFF',
          trackBackgroundColor: '#404043',
          trackBorderColor: '#404043'
       },

       // special colors for some of the
       legendBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
       background2: '#505053',
       dataLabelsColor: '#B0B0B3',
       textColor: '#C0C0C0',
       contrastTextColor: '#F0F0F3',
       maskColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.3)'
    };

    // Apply the theme
    Highcharts.setOptions(Highcharts.theme);






        var gaugeOptions = {

            chart: {
                type: 'solidgauge',
            },

            title: null,

            pane: {
                center: ['50%', '85%'],
                size: '140%',
                startAngle: -90,
                endAngle: 90,
                background: {
                    backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#EEE',
                    innerRadius: '60%',
                    outerRadius: '100%',
                    shape: 'arc'
                }
            },

            tooltip: {
                enabled: false
            },

            // the value axis
            yAxis: {
                stops: [
                    [0.1, '#55BF3B'], // green
                    [0.5, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
                    [0.9, '#DF5353'] // red
                ],
                lineWidth: 0,
                minorTickInterval: null,
                tickPixelInterval: 400,
                tickWidth: 0,
                title: {
                    y: -70,
                },
                labels: {
                    y: 16,

                }        
            },

            plotOptions: {
                solidgauge: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled:true,
                        useHTML: true,
                        backgroundColor:'#000000',
                        color:'#FF6699',
                        crop:false,
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        // The speed gauge
        $('#container-speed').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                max: 200,
                title: {
                    text: 'Speed'
                }       
            },

            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Speed',
                data: [80],
                dataLabels: {
                        enabled:true,
                        backgroundColor:'#000000',
                        color:'#FF6699',
                        crop:false,
                    style: {
                        color: '#FF6699',
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        fontSize:'25px'
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: ' km/h'
                }
            }]

        }));

        // The RPM gauge
        $('#container-rpm').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                max: 5,
                title: {
                    text: 'RPM'
                }       
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'RPM',
                data: [1],
                dataLabels: {
                    format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' + 
                        ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y:.1f}</span><br/>' + 
                        '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">* 1000 / min</span></div>'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: ' revolutions/min'
                }      
            }]

        }));

        // Bring life to the dials
        setInterval(function () {
            // Speed
            var chart = $('#container-speed').highcharts();
            if (chart) {
                var point = chart.series[0].points[0],
                    newVal,
                    inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 100);

                newVal = point.y + inc;
                if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 200) {
                    newVal = point.y - inc;
                }

                point.update(newVal);
            }

            // RPM
            chart = $('#container-rpm').highcharts();
            if (chart) {
                var point = chart.series[0].points[0],
                    newVal,
                    inc = Math.random() - 0.5;

                newVal = point.y + inc;
                if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 5) {
                    newVal = point.y - inc;
                }

                point.update(newVal);
            }
        }, 2000);  





    });

    </script>



    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.src.js"></script>

    <div style="width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto; " >
        <div id="container-speed" style="width: 300px; height: 200px; float: left; "></div>
        <div id="container-rpm" style="width: 300px; height: 200px; float: left; "></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You have a lot of dangling commas which IE does not take kindly to. Remove those and see if it still fails. If it does check your console for errors.

Comment: It's a bug in 4.0.1 of solid gauge. Already fixed on master branch, will be included in 4.0.2 release.